# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object ? the following error is coming in this programme why?

Tags: python

```
options = get_arguments()
#change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
print(ifconfig_result)
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_address_search_result.group(0) )
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best way to get help for stuff like this is to add some explanation of what you're trying to accomplish and provide a reproducible example that someone else can run and debug. That way, you're more likely to get the help you need. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` returns the output as bytes by default, and `re.search` requires that the search string be a string rather than bytes.

You can either use the `bytes.decode` method to convert `ifconfig_result` to a string:

```
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w",
    ifconfig_result.decode())
```

or if you're using Python 3.6+, pass an `encoding` argument to `subprocess.check_output` so that it returns a string instead:

```
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(
    ["ifconfig", options.interface], encoding='utf-8')
```